# Upload bulk data in the sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am creating new Generic List using CSOM. Now I want to add records into it. But as the data records are huge in numbers, there can be lots of client context execution requests. How can I upload data to List in bulk ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can crate your own batch mechanism. For example execute query for every 200 items. The batch size can be much greater, but it depends on how much field you are setting in the item.

This code generate 10000 items in 50 calls.

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://some-site-url"))
{
    // use proper credentials

    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List");

    int batchSize = 200;
    int currentBatch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ListItem item = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
        item["Title"] = "Some value";
        item.Update();

        if (currentBatch >= batchSize)
        {
            // Reset the batch
            currentBatch = 0;
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }

    // Execute query one more time if the barch size is less then batchSize
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where and in which format you have data

If you have data in excel, csv format.
 - Go to List, open ribbon context and find export to excel options. 
   click on it, it will download an owssvry.iqy file. 
 -  once download completes, open this file, it will basically make connection 
   to sharepoint and load you existing data in excel sheet.  Please note
   that it will only export columsn which are in current view when you
   used export to excel option.
 - open your source excel and arrange columns data according to you list view columns sequence.
 - do a simple copy paste operation as we do in excel to excel. 
 - Source excel to *.iqy excel. 
 - one done, just save your *.iqy file and it will create item in sharepoint list

If you want to do it via CSOM, there is no other option to read source and create data row by row using CSOM code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to bulk upload data in Sharepoint List

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://some-site-url"))
{
    // use proper credentials

    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List");

    int batchSize = 200;
    int currentBatch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ListItem item = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
        item["Title"] = "Some value";
        item.Update();
        currentBatch++;
        if (currentBatch >= batchSize)
        {
            // Reset the batch
            currentBatch = 0;
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }

    // Execute query one more time if the barch size is less then batchSize
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```